# Exclude folder and files when using get-childitem in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm not sure how I should be excluding the following:
 `.env, web.config, node_modules`

```
$sourceRoot = "C:\Users\Wade Aston\Desktop\STEMuli\server"
$destinationRoot = "C:\Users\Wade Aston\Desktop\STEMuli/server-sandbox"
$dir = get-childitem $sourceRoot -Exclude .env, web.config, node_modules <-- How do I exclude these       
$i=1
$dir| %{
    [int]$percent = $i / $dir.count * 100
    Write-Progress -Activity "Copying ... ($percent %)" -status $_  -PercentComplete $percent -verbose
    $_ | copy -Destination $destinationRoot  -Recurse -Force
    $i++
}
```

Thank you =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a couple of notes: 
* Try using wildcards, to apply exclusion, like: *.env
* Copy-Item parameter Source, allows using collection of type String. Using collection should be faster, than processing sequential with foreach!
* If you need only the files, you may consider using Get-ChildItem -File

You may try something like:

```
$Source = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\TEMP -Exclude dism.log, *.csv 
$dest = 'C:\temp2'

Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $dest -Force
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

To exclude both certain files like '*.env' and 'web.config' AND also exclude a folder with a certain name, you could do this:

```
$sourceRoot      = "C:\Users\Wade Aston\Desktop\STEMuli\server"
$destinationRoot = "C:\Users\Wade Aston\Desktop\STEMuli\server-sandbox"

$dir = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceRoot -Recurse -File -Exclude '*.env', 'web.config' | 
       Where-Object{ $_.DirectoryName -notmatch 'node_modules' }

$i = 1
$dir | ForEach-Object {
    [int]$percent = $i / $dir.count * 100
    Write-Progress -Activity "Copying ... ($percent %)" -Status $_  -PercentComplete $percent -Verbose

    $target = Join-Path -Path $destinationRoot -ChildPath $_.DirectoryName.Substring($sourceRoot.Length)
    # create the target destination folder if it does not already exist
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $target -PathType Container)) {
        New-Item -Path $target -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
    }
    $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $target -Force
    $i++
}
```